# What page to open when running Maven-based EAR from Netbeans

Tags: maven-2, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

Is there an easy way to tell Netbeans (6.9) what page to open when I "run" my Maven Enterprise project? It opens a totally wrong **context path**. I guess there are some options I can specify on the Project Properties | Actions page -> "Run project" action, I just can't find it anywhere as documentation seems to be nonexistent for Netbeans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are running into http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=176096. I haven't found a fix for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specified relative url in *Project properties / run*?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. It is the context path that is wrong (which is part of the URL). I do not run the web project (because it says "In-place deployment..." but doesn't do anything other than compile), I run the Assembly project instead.